# Using jQuery or Javascript to find dropdown option value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am dynamically generating a dropdown list on the page when a user loads it. I'd like to get the value of the dropdown using jquery or javascript.

The tricky part is that the dropdown will have a value as such:
"I love Rabbits ($19.95)"

I want to get the value of the dropdown and then isolate the value inside of the brackets.
Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Some code, and maybe a fiddle, would surely help in answering the question ?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting the value is easy, use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val). That will be a string.

Then you just grab the value with a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), probably with a capture group; for instance:

```
var value, m, innerValue;
value = $("selector for select box").val();
m = /\(([^)]+)/.exec(value);
if (m) {
    innerValue = m[1];
}
```

That regex says: "Find a `(` and then capture everything following it that isn't a `)`". Then we take the value of the capture group.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply T.J. I am a beginner to JQ/JS, and I am having a hard time getting the value this assigns innerValue into my input box. I read examples and it says "Then do [...]" but I don't know what "do" means.

Comment: *"I am having a hard time getting the value this assigns innerValue into my input box..."* I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm unsure how to explain it but I'll try. I put the above code on my page and edited the "value". When I select a dropdown, the value of it does not display in my input box. I don't know how to get it to at all, I'm at a loss for that part.

Answer (score 3):

Could you not have your select in the following format:

```
<select name="opinions_price">
<option value="19.45">I love rabbits (£19.45)</option>
<option value="12.45">I hate parakeets (£12.45)</option>
<option value="3.24">I am indifferent to possums (£3.24)</option>
</select>
```

Then simply do:

```
var price = $('select option:selected').val();
```

If you want to use the data attributes instead (assume the select is in a loop, you know how to do that):

```
<select name="opinions_price">
<?php foreach($things as $thing) { ?>
<option data-price="<?php echo $thing['price']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $thing['id']; ?>">[..]</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Then simply do:

```
var price = $('select option:selected').data('price');
var id = $('select option:selected').data('id');
```

Saves a (possibly) expensive Regex?

Comment: +1 for the solution, but don't use `attr('value')`, as it may not work. Rather, use `val()`.

Comment: Sadly can't use this because I am submitting a form and the value of the option is the row[id]

Comment: Have you considered using the data-* attribute that jQuery now brings to the table. Have edited answer to show you.